# Проверка вводимых данных

Tags: c++, while, switch

Пишу цикл `while` в нем есть `switch` (выбор `case` зависит от переменной типа `int`) если ввести букву/символ то программа падает.
Нужно реализовать проверку на символы/буквы... Гуглил, но ответа не нашел внятного. Сам я вроде понимаю, что нужно сверить тип присваиваемой переменной, но увы не могу реализовать.
Реализовать простую проверку на цифры труда не составило, а вот на буквы/символы уже проблема...

```
while (ace) {
    std::cout << "Please select an action: ";
    std::cin >> a;

    switch (a) {
        case 1: {
            Sort1();
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            std::cout << "Hello 2" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            std::cout << "Hello 3" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        case 4: {
            std::cout << "\nВы вышли из программы" << std::endl;
            system("pause");
            ace = false;
            break;
        }
        default:
            std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Код покажите, без этого вопрос никакого смысла не имеет. Во всяком случае никаких проблем приведения символа к int в C++ нет, в том числе и для switch. А если программа "падает" (именно падает, а не идёт по не той ветке алгоритма), то проблема может вовсе и не в этом.

Comment: @Pink Tux дополнил, там не то что она падает а начинает циклически бежать текст

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while( ace )
{
   std::cout << "Please select an action: ";
   std::string input;
   std::cin >> input;
   /*
     дальше переводим строку input в число. ошибка - ругаемся
     и вводим заново. получии валидный int - отдаём его в switch
   */
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, сделал :)